# Sum the repeated input values if it contains the same type of class or identifier

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I was designing an electronic billing system using the programming languages HTML & CSS & JavaScript & PHP, but I stumbled upon the following example as I cannot collect values from the duplicate input inside the table. I cannot do this while sending data to an SQL table because SQL only enters the last value for the field and I also want to collect data from fields using JavaScript. I would like to collect data with SQL & JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <style type="text/css">
    tr th,input{
      padding: 0.07rem!important;
    }
  </style> 
</head> 
<?php 
 /* $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','billing_app') or die('KO');
   $err='';
  if ($conn) {
   if (isset($_POST['add-row'])) {
      
       if (empty($_POST['x1'])) {
        echo "Err";
       }else{
        $x1 = $_POST['x1'];
        $sql =  mysqli_query($conn," INSERT INTO x1(x1)VALUES('$x1')");
        if ($sql) {
         $err =  "sql OK";
        }else{
        $err =  "sql NOT OK";
        }
        }
       
     }
   }
*/
 ?>
<body> 
  <form action="temp.php" method="POST">
    <a href="JavaScript:void(0)" class="add-row w3-button lightblue w3-large" style="padding: 0.00rem 0.09rem!important">أضف صفا </a>)  
    <div class="w3-container w3-section ">
        <table class="w3-table-all w3-centered odd-red" dir="rtl">
        <tr>
          <th>الرقم </th> 
          <th>اسم العنصر  </th>
          <th>رقم العنصر  </th>
          <th>الكمية  </th>
          <th>سعر الوحدة (الواحدة)  </th>
          <th>الخصم </th>
          <th>إجمالي البنود</th>
        </tr>
        <script> 
         let lineNo = 1; 
         $(document).ready(function () { 
             $(".add-row").click(function () { 
                 markup = "<tr>"+"<th><input name='x1' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' value="+lineNo+"></th>"+"<th><input name='x2' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"<th><input name='x3' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"<th><input name='x4' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"<th><input name='x5' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"<th><input name='x6' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"<th><input name='x7' class='w3-input foc-outl-green txt-blue w3-border w3-center' id=''></th>"+"</tr>"; 
                 tableBody = $("table tbody"); 
                 tableBody.append(markup); 
                 lineNo++;
             }); 
         });
        </script> 
        </table>
        <?php/* echo $err;*/?>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="add-row">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use name as array `name="x1[]"... name="x2[]" ...`

Comment: In your code,  you are only checking for x1. Is there a reason for that?